# Puppeteer: Staying on page too long closes the browser (Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed)

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

My plan is to connect to a page, interact with its elements for a while, and then wait and start over. Since the process of accessing the page is complicated, I would ideally log in only once, and then permanently stay on page.

**index.js**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const creds = require("./creds.json");

(async () => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://www.online-messenger.com');

        await goToChats(page);
        await page.waitForSelector('div[aria-label="Chats"]');

        setInterval(async () => {
            let index = 1;
            while (index <= 5) {
                if (await isUnread(page, index)) {
                    await page.click(`#local-chat`);
                    await page.waitForSelector('div[role="main"]');

                    let conversationName = await getConversationName(page);
                    if (isChat(conversationName)) {
                        await writeMessage(page);
                    }
                }
                index++;
            }
        }, 30000);
    } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Again, I do not want to close the connection, so I thought add the *setInterval()* would help me with the problem. **The core code works absolutely fine**, but every single time I run the code with the interval function I get this error:

```
Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed.
```

I timed the main part of my code and it would typically take around 20-25 seconds. I thought the problem lies in the delay set to 30 seconds, but I get the same error even when I increase it to e.g. 60000 (60 seconds).

What am I doing wrong? Why is setInterval not working, and is there possibly a different way of tackling my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after spending some more time on the problem, I realised it was indeed the `setInterval` function that caused all the errors.

The code is asynchronous and in order to make it all work, I had to use an '`async`' version of `setInterval()`. I wrapped my code in an endless loop, which finishes with promise, which resolves after a specified time.

```
...

  await goToChats(page);
  await page.waitForSelector('div[aria-label="Chats"]');

  while(true) {
    let index = 1;
    while (index <= 5) {

    if (await isUnread(page, index)) {
      await page.click(`#local-chat`);
      await page.waitForSelector('div[role="main"]');

      let conversationName = await getConversationName(page);
      if (isChat(conversationName)) {
        await writeMessage(page);
      }
    }
    waitBeforeNextIteration(10000);
    index++;
   }
   
...
```

```
waitBeforeNextIteration(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}
```